# How can I access an embedded resource in a .Net DLL from another (test) .Net dll?

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit, embedded-resource

I’m trying to write a unit test that accesses a resource that I’ve associated with a project.  Here is the general structure.  The resource has strings intended to be used by MyLibClass and the class is set to `en-US`

```
Solution1
--MyLibrary
  --Properties
     --AssemblyInfo.cs
     --Resources.resx
     --Resource.Designer.cs
  --References
  --MyLibClass.cs

--MyLibrary.Tests
  --Properties
     --AssemblyInfo.cs
  --References
  --MyLibClassTests.cs

--MainProject
```

The test needs to set up the class and pass it the ResourceManager because I’m trying to use Dependency Injection. I get the error below when I try to load using the code below in the test.

Since the resource is embedded in the MyLibrary.dll how does MyLibraryTest.dll access it?

```
  resmgr = new ResourceManager("MyLibrary",
                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

The error in NUnit

```
MyLibrary.Tests. MyLibClassTests.IsInValidMyProperty_Blank:
An unexpected exception type was thrown
Expected: System.ArgumentException
 but was: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException : Could not find any
resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
"MyLibrary.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyLibrary.Tests"
at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and
fully signed.
```

So after thinking about it, the dll's are in separate project folders.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: executingassembly is your test dll, you want the assembly that you are testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample you already passing assembly to load resources from - you just for some reason use assembly that do not contain resource you are looking for. Most likely you need to pass the same assembly where `MyLibClass` is, not `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` which I assume gives you assembly of the test code.

```
resmgr = new ResourceManager("MyLibrary",
    typeof(MyLibClass).Assembly);
```

Comment: Makes sense, but It tells me that 'MyLibClass' is a namespace but used like a 'type'.

Comment: @RichShealer - it is your code I have no idea what classes are in that assembly where resources are. Often class name matches file name, so I assumed that "MyLibClass" is name of the class, but it seems to be namespace in your code. Just find a class in that assembly and use it. Note that if you name class and namespace the same you'll get some confusing issues due to name resolution from time to time.

Comment: That helped. It never occurred to me that I needed a class. I thought I needed something higher up to identify the module.

Comment: In addition the basename had to be changed to from `"MyLibrary"` to `"MyLibrary.Properties.Resources"`. There was also a problem that the resource was not showing up in the object browser. I deleted the resource, closed the project, reopened and recreated it.